# You do not have permission to edit this user

Tags: multisite

I am using wordpress mu. My blog administrators are unable to edit users - getting the message: You do not have permission to edit this user. I have checked my plugins etc and cannot find the cause. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is set in wp-config.php: define( "EDIT_ANY_USER", true );

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that has been revisited in newer versions of multisite -- the justification for removing the ability for blog-specific admins to edit users is that user profile information is shared among blogs, so that admin is effectively editing information that would affect the user across the install. So, they've updated permissions so that only multi-site super-admins can edit user profiles by default.